# How to copy URL from Hyperlink in Adobe Reader DC?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader

I really cannot believe that Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, a highly professional application, on Windows 10, a highly professional OS, would not have the facility to copy a URL -- but this is what I get when I right click on a hyperlink in a PDF opened there:

[image: adobe-reader-right-click-url]

So, how can I copy an URL from a PDF opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC ?

Comment: Use the Select Tool, Select the Hyperlink, Press <ctrl><c> ...

Comment: @DavidPostill That only copies the text, not the URL.

Comment: The only way I can see to copy the URL is to open the PDF in Firefox or Chrome, which have their own custom code for displaying PDF's.

Comment: This annoys me also a lot.

Answer (score 21):

As @worthwelle mentioned in a comment, my current workaround is to

1. save the PDF locally (if not)
2. navigate in the file explorer to the file
3. right-click open with Chrome (not Adobe reader)
4. In Chrome go to the link you want to get the url, right-click and 'copy link address'

   By default my browser opens PDF with the Adobe Reader (not the browser PDF viewer). If it is not the case for you copying the url of the pdf file in Chrome browser address bar might be enough (no need to save the file locally).

Comment: This doesn't work if the remote server redirects you to another web address.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to Chrome, as is the case at my work, you can open the PDF with MS Word and convert it to .DOCX
Find the hyperlink, right click and edit.
Huge pain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a revoltingly terrible answer (and I will not fault anyone for not upvoting it), but today I was able to hover over the link in Acrobat Reader with my mouse, whereupon the tooltop displayed the URL I wanted, then open another window running a text editor, and retype the link in there, i.e. copy-by-eyeball.  The saving grace was that while Acrobat Reader was in the background (my text editor being in the foreground) the tooltip still displayed, so the transcription was at least straightforward.  (Hopping back and forth between Acrobat Reader and my text editor would have been even more annoying!)

Comment: not a good answer really! 

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat painstaking process that combines the power of Word docs and Google,

1. go to your Google Drive (logged in) and open an empty Google doc
2. Upload the said pdf file into Google doc (you're trying to open the PDF as a Google doc).
3. Now copy the link from the PDF by hovering over and copying the link

This is somewhat combining @ThierryDalon and @Tracy answers, but hope this helps anyways.

Answer (score -1):

*As of 2021, easy solution*

Use select tool, double click the embedded link, and a pop up asks if it should connect to the site. Approve, and you're there!